# What is the computational class of a pushdown automaton with real values?

Tags: pushdown-automata, complexity-classes, turing-completeness, real-numbers

Say there is a push-down automaton, in this example I'll use a [Deadfish](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish)-like set:

`+: increase x by 1`

`0: set x to 0`

`ln: set x to ln(x) <-- real valued result`

With x being an infinite precision real-valued variable, does this allow said machine to have more power than if it was operating on integers? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Could you describe this push-down automaton ?

Answer (score 0):

Since none of your instructions can influence the behavior of the pushdown automaton (they can only influence the value of $x$), this does not change which languages the pushdown automaton can accept.